# how to calculate YTD average for each day in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
dates      product price
```

| 2020-01-01 | laptop | 210 |

| 2020-01-01 | pc     | 100 |

| 2020-01-02 | laptop | 150 |

| 2020-01-02 | pc     | 200 |

| 2020-01-03 | laptop | 150 |

| 2021-01-01 | pc     | 110 |

| 2021-01-01 | laptop | 220 |

2021-01-02 | pc     | 210 |

2021-01-02 | laptop | 200 |

2021-01-03 | pc     | 260 |

it is necessary to calculate the average value since the beginning of the year for each day, by product
For example. Add the date 2020.01.02 to 2020.01.01 and divide by two(150+210)/2

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

`SELECT product, AVG(price) FROM your_table WHERE dates >= '2021-01-01' GROUP BY product`

`SELECT dates, AVG(price) FROM your_table WHERE dates >= '2021-01-01' GROUP BY dates`

`SELECT product, dates, AVG(price) FROM your_table WHERE dates >= '2021-01-01' GROUP BY product, dates`

I don't know mysql but in sql server and oracle database it would be something like that.

Comment: I think one Avg will not be enough, because it is necessary that the number from the date of the third day, for example, be added to the first and divided by two. And so absolutely every day

Comment: OK, then I got you wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH YOUR_TABLE_DATA (DATED,PRODUCT,PRICE)AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE)DATED,'laptop',  210 UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2020-01-01',  'pc',  100 UNION ALL 
  SELECT'2020-01-02' , 'laptop',  150 UNION ALL 
  SELECT'2020-01-02',  'pc',  200 UNION ALL 
  SELECT'2020-01-03',  'laptop',  150 UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2021-01-01',  'pc' , 110 UNION ALL 
  SELECT'2021-01-01',  'laptop',  220 UNION ALL 
  SELECT'2021-01-02',  'pc',  210 UNION ALL 
  SELECT'2021-01-02',  'laptop',  200 UNION ALL 
  SELECT'2021-01-03',  'pc',  260  
)
SELECT C.DATED,C.PRODUCT,C.PRICE,
 AVG(C.PRICE)OVER(PARTITION BY C.PRODUCT ORDER BY C.DATED ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)X_AVG
FROM YOUR_TABLE_DATA AS C
ORDER BY C.PRODUCT,C.DATED
```

Tested on MySQL8.0
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0124122a665975bf096ff02ea4832f0